Why does closing a memory stream used to create an Image object effect a new Image object?
Question:
Why does a MemoryStream object used for ImageA effect a cloned Image object named ImageB?  I know Microsoft says that when you create an Image object from a memory stream you have to leave that stream open for the life of the image.  But I'm trying to create ImageA from a MemoryStream, clone ImageA to ImageB, then dispose of ImageA and the MemoryStream used to create ImageA.  I get errors working with ImageB afterwards.
Source Examples:
All the code below is used to create a new multi-page tiff image from 3 tiff files (single page).  Ending up with a single tiff image that is 3 pages.
From this you gain...

Image newImg
MemoryStream ms

Note: This might seem like a lot of code for a small test but I wanted to give a really good example of where I'm getting the objects I'm working with.  A lot of this example code was taken from a few different methods/functions and I just changed around a few things to really paint a picture of everything I'm doing from the importing of the file itself.
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"c:\test\page001.tif");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
List<Image> imagesToAdd = new List<Image>()
{
    Image.FromFile(@"c:\test\page002.tif"),
    Image.FromFile(@"c:\test\page003.tif")
};

// Create compression encoder parameter
EncoderParameter compressionParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);

// Create first page frame parameter
EncoderParameter firstFrameParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

// Create additional pages frame parameter
EncoderParameter additionalFramesParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);

// Create color depth parameter
EncoderParameter colorDepthParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, (long)1);

// Create flush parameter
EncoderParameter flushParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);

// Create last frame parameter
EncoderParameter lastPageParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.LastFrame);

// Create first page encoder parameters
EncoderParameters firstFrameParams = new EncoderParameters(2)
{
    Param = new EncoderParameter[]
    {
            compressionParam,
            firstFrameParam,
    }
};

// Create additional pages encoder parameters
EncoderParameters additionalFrameParams = new EncoderParameters(2)
{
    Param = new EncoderParameter[]
    {
            compressionParam,
            additionalFramesParam,
    }
};

// Create save to file encoder parameters
EncoderParameters saveToFileParams = new EncoderParameters(2)
{
    Param = new EncoderParameter[]
    {
            compressionParam,
            colorDepthParam,
    }
};

// Create flush encoder parameters
EncoderParameters flushParams = new EncoderParameters(1)
{
    Param = new EncoderParameter[]
    {
            flushParam,
            lastPageParam,
    }
};

// Get the tiff image codec
ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Where(c => c.MimeType == "image/tiff").First();

// Save the first page to memory stream
img.Save(ms, codec, firstFrameParams);

// Save aditional pages to memory stream
foreach (Image image in imagesToAdd)
    img.SaveAdd(image, additionalFrameParams);

// Finalize the new multi-page image
img.SaveAdd(flushParams);

//Image newImg = pageOne.SaveMultiPageImage(imgCol, out MemoryStream ms);
Image newImg = Image.FromStream(ms);

// Cleanup
firstFrameParams.Dispose();
additionalFrameParams.Dispose();
saveToFileParams.Dispose();
flushParam.Dispose();
compressionParam.Dispose();
firstFrameParam.Dispose();
additionalFramesParam.Dispose();
colorDepthParam.Dispose();
flushParam.Dispose();
lastPageParam.Dispose();

Below code is really used in another place. I have made all this one function for testing to make a good example. The idea with the code below is to work with the image produced with code above, then make a clone of it, delete the original image and the memory stream used to create it, then try to work with the newly created Image object.
Issue: After disposing the memorystream used to create newImg Image object, the new image (newImg2) that was cloned from newImg becomes corrupt.
// Try to work with the newImg Image object (no issues)
int pageCount = newImg.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
{
    newImg.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
    Debug.WriteLine($"BEFORE - Page:{i + 1}  W/H: {newImg.Width}/{newImg.Height}");
}

// Create a new Image (newImg2) based on the original Image (newImg)
// then dispose of the original Image object as it's no longer needed
Image newImg2 = (Image)newImg.Clone();
newImg.Dispose();

// This causes issues when dealing with newImg2 going forward
ms.Dispose();

// Try to work with the newImg2 Image object (issues)
pageCount = newImg2.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
{
    newImg2.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
    Debug.WriteLine($"AFTER - Page:{i + 1}  W/H: {newImg2.Width}/{newImg2.Height}");
}


Using Clone() is like copying a pointer or reference. Both images (the original and the clone) are sharing the same underlying memory/image data in the original MemoryStream.
Because of this, disposing ms means the memory that holds that image data for both is released and no longer valid. All images that reference this MemoryStream fail when they try to access its content.
If you intend on closing the memoryStream here, ensure that newImg2 is a completely independent copy.
using (MemoryStream cloneStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    newImg.Save(cloneStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);
    tempStream.Position = 0;
    newImg2 = Image.FromStream(cloneStream);
}

This must be done before calling
ms.Dispose();

Alternatively, (see comments, and thank you)
MemoryStream newMs = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
Image imgClone = Image.FromStream(newMs);
ms.Dispose();


But that in itself would not work would it?  Don't you need to irritate through each page and do a SaveAdd call etc?  This example would only give you the first page wouldn't it?

Also, why did MS do that?  It sounds like it's the same thing as doing Image ImageB = ImageA they end up being the same object right?  If you did a clone to ImageB then changed a property on ImageA, wouldn't the cloned ImageB have that same property change?

You're right, cloneStream without iteration would only save the first page, I'll sketch out a more robust solution in the answer.
Image imageB = ImageA creates a reference copy, yeah. Both are the same object in memory, and changing imageA will show on imageB. The complication here comes from backing the image with a Stream and cloning  - Clone() can still result in references on imageB to the original memory stream. However, changing, say, the dimensions of imageA after cloning will not be reflected in imageB.
Why? Harder to say. Shallow copies are usually used for efficiency

Thanks for the info @Blue!  Really helped confirm some things for me.

Also, side note...  Sounds like I need to write an extension method for Image.CloneForReal().  lol

One last thing, for a true clone, could I not just clone the MemoryStream contents?  Like MemoryStream newMs = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray())?  Then do something like Image img = Image.FromStream(newMs)?  Avoiding all the irritations and objects being created to repack each image page?

Oh lord, yeah you should be able to do just that, updated the answer to reflect. Thank you so much

My only concern is the after math.   If I made that an extension method (working on it right now), I would return the real cloned Image object.  But the memory stream (though left open) would be created and left behind.  Does Image.Dispose() by chance handle the cleanup of the underlying MemoryStream?  For example, If I have Image B, C, and D all cloned from A.  Then Disposed of A, B, and C and later down the timeline, Disposed of D, would that Dispose of the MemoryStream all of them were using?

Image.Dispose() does not manage or dispose of the Stream.
That said, an extension method could manage the cloned memory stream. The using syntax here does handle the disposal/lifecycle of the stream
`public static Image CloneAsNewImage(this Image image)
{
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
    ms.Position = 0;
    return Image.FromStream(ms);
}

}`

That would create a corrupt image returned though.  It would return an Image created from a MemoryStream you have since closed.  The only way something like this would work is to keep the MemoryStream open and I guess use something like GetStream() in another extension method to dispose the underlying stream.

it looks like it might actual do just that!  Per MS page... `Calling the Dispose method allows the resources used by this Image to be reallocated for other purposes.
Call Dispose when you are finished using the Image. The Dispose method leaves the Image in an unusable state. After calling Dispose, you must release all references to the Image so the garbage collector can reclaim the memory that the Image was occupying.`

Promising but a little dubious - I'd test that it actually disposes of the Stream - best practice imo would be to explicitly close streams anyway.
The cloned image created by the CloneAsNewImage extension should not be affected if you dispose the original MemoryStream, because it creates an image from its own locally-scoped and independent stream

I'm almost positive (this situation is in my original question) it does throw GDI+ errors if you destroy the memory stream from which the new image was created.  Anytime you create an image from a stream you have to keep that stream alive for the life of the new image or GDI+ errors will occur.

You're correct, I just tested and even using GC.Collect() and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() I still the MemoryStream populated.  Maybe one of the "references" they talk about it the MemoryStream itself lol.  However, about the image turning out corrupt, I'm almost positive (this situation is in my original question) it does throw GDI+ errors if you destroy the memory stream from which the new image was created. Anytime you create an image from a stream you have to keep that stream alive for the life of the new image or GDI+ errors will occur.

So the answer to the question is simply both ImageA and ImageB are using the same MemoryStream under the hood.
In case someone wants a solution like me to make a real clone of an Image object, I have created an extension method to handle this.
public static Image CloneToNewStream(this Image img)
{
    SaveMultiPageImage(img, 0, null, out MemoryStream msOrg, true, true, null);
    MemoryStream msNew = new MemoryStream(msOrg.ToArray());
    msOrg.Dispose();

    return Image.FromStream(msNew);
}

My only concern here is that a new MemoryStream object is created and never disposed of.  Normally one would always try and clean up the objects that support the IDisposable Interface with something like a using () { } block.  However whenever you create an Image object from a MemoryStream you cannot dispose of the MemoryStream.  It has to exist for the life of the Image object.  Otherwise you will start seeing GDI+ generic errors during runtime.
Also referencing this quote found on this page,

Calling the Dispose method allows the resources used by this Image to
be reallocated for other purposes.
Call Dispose when you are finished using the Image. The Dispose method
leaves the Image in an unusable state. After calling Dispose, you must
release all references to the Image so the garbage collector can
reclaim the memory that the Image was occupying.
Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the
Image. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until
the garbage collector calls the Image object's Finalize method.

It seems that if there are no references to the Image object the underlying MemoryStream will be cleaned up by the Garbage Collector.
Example:
// Note: ms is a MemeoryStream
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
Image img2 = img.Clone();
img.Dispose();
img = null;
img2.Dispose();
img2 = null;

Furthermore, I started thinking about it and when you call Image img = Image.FromFile() you never have access to a MemoryStream.  Yet when you Dispose of an Image object there are not memory leaks.  So I think the GC will handle cleaning up what is not used later on.
